# Unit testing react hook inside react-admin

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jestjs, react-admin

Is there any way to mock the user authenticated status using useAuthState as a mock?

Things i have tried so far include: React Hooks Testing Library, Enzyme component rendering, jest.mock, jest.createMockFromModule. I know if i don't include my component inside a provider i will get "could not find react-redux context value; please ensure the component is wrapped in a Provider"

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import { useAuthState } from 'ra-core';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router';
import { Routes } from '../../ui/constants';
import { UnAuthenticatedLayoutWithTheme } from '../UnAuthenticatedLayout';

export const GettingStarted = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const { loading, authenticated } = useAuthState();

    if (loading) {
        return null;
    }

    if (authenticated) {
        return <Redirect to={Routes.default} />;
    }

    return (
        <UnAuthenticatedLayoutWithTheme showActions>
            <Typography
                variant="h3"
                align="center"
                className={classes.sectionTitle}
            >
                Onboarding
            </Typography>
...
```

```
test('should display page with user not authenticated', async() => {
        const { getByText } = renderWithRedux(
            <ApiHubProvider url="/getting-started" tenantName="getting-started">
                 <GettingStarted />
            </ApiHubProvider>
        );

        await wait(() => {
            expect(getByText('Onboarding')).not.toBeNull();
        });
    });
```

ApiHubProvider Implementation

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useRef } from 'react';
import get from 'lodash/get';

export const ApiHubContext = createContext();

export const ApiHubProvider = ({
    url,
    tenantName,
    originHubName,
    children,
}) => {
    const value = useRef({
        originHubName,
        tenantName,
        url,
        urlWithApi: `${url}/api`,
        urlWithTenant: `${url}/api/${tenantName}`,
    });
    return (
        <ApiHubContext.Provider value={value.current}>
            {children}
        </ApiHubContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`react-admin` provides a set of testing utilities for testing like `renderHook`, add `ra-test` to your devDependencies.

This are mentioned here: [https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Architecture.html#:~:text=ra%2Dtest%3A%20Utilities%20for%20testing%20react%2Dadmin%20apps%20and%20components](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Architecture.html#:%7E:text=ra%2Dtest%3A%20Utilities%20for%20testing%20react%2Dadmin%20apps%20and%20components).

Also read the docs on how to do testing:
https://marmelab.com/react-admin/UnitTesting.html